# Parsing CSV and Analysing Data

Tags: python, csv, indexing

I'm doing a bit of homework via Hacker Rank, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not accepting my answer.

[Here is the link to the original repository.](https://github.com/thisismetis/dsp/blob/master/python/q8_parsing.py)

The goal is to print the name of the team that has the smallest difference between its Goals and Goals Allowed values.

There seem to be two possibilities, Leicester and Aston_Villa because Leicester has a negative difference between goals scored and goals allowed (-37) whereas Aston_Villa has the smallest absolute difference (-1). Neither of these are accepted however.

Any thoughts as to why?

```
import sys
import os
import csv

text = '''Team,Games,Wins,Losses,Draws,Goals,Goals Allowed,Points
Arsenal,38,26,9,3,79,36,87
Liverpool,38,24,8,6,67,30,80
Manchester United,38,24,5,9,87,45,77
Newcastle,38,21,8,9,74,52,71
Leeds,38,18,12,8,53,37,66
Chelsea,38,17,13,8,66,38,64
West_Ham,38,15,8,15,48,57,53
Aston_Villa,38,12,14,12,46,47,50
Tottenham,38,14,8,16,49,53,50
Blackburn,38,12,10,16,55,51,46
Southampton,38,12,9,17,46,54,45
Middlesbrough,38,12,9,17,35,47,45
Fulham,38,10,14,14,36,44,44
Charlton,38,10,14,14,38,49,44
Everton,38,11,10,17,45,57,43
Bolton,38,9,13,16,44,62,40
Sunderland,38,10,10,18,29,51,40
Ipswich,38,9,9,20,41,64,36
Derby,38,8,6,24,33,63,30
Leicester,38,5,13,20,30,64,28'''

with open('football.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)



def read_data(filename):
    """Returns a list of lists representing the rows of the csv file data.

    Arguments: filename is the name of a csv file (as a string)
    Returns: list of lists of strings, where every line is split into a list of values. 
        ex: ['Arsenal', 38, 26, 9, 3, 79, 36, 87]
    """ 
    ifile = open('football.csv', 'rt')
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)

    listed = []
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        listed.append(row)

    return listed

data = read_data('football.csv')

def get_index_with_min_abs_score_difference(goals):
    net_goals = []

    for i in goals[1:]:
        net_goals.append(int(i[5]) - int(i[6]))

    return net_goals.index(min(net_goals))+1

def get_team(index_value, parsed_data):
    return parsed_data[index_value][0]

footballTable = read_data('football.csv')
minRow = get_index_with_min_abs_score_difference(footballTable)
print(str(get_team(minRow, footballTable)))
```

I've also tried the alternate solution (i.e. the team with the smallest absolute difference between goals scored and goals allowed).

```
def get_index_with_min_abs_score_difference(goals):
    """Returns the index of the team with the smallest difference
    between 'for' and 'against' goals, in terms of absolute value.

    Arguments: parsed_data is a list of lists of cleaned strings
    Returns: integer row index
    """
    net_goals = []

    for i in goals[1:]:
        net_goals.append(abs(int(i[5]) - int(i[6])))

    return net_goals.index(min(net_goals))+1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You've put together a very nicely worded question indeed. Additionally, a link to the challenge in question would nicely supplement your writeup here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but instead I have some comments on your solution.

You're spending a bunch of lines reading a csv file row by row only to put it into a list (which later on you will process item by item), and then later on you have some special logic to skip over the header row.  Your solution would be much simpler if you were to use a `csv.DictReader` instead, and just use the resulting iterator directly rather than trying to read it into a list first.  Consider the output of:

```
with open('football.csv', 'rt') as ifile:                                       
    footballTable = csv.DictReader(ifile)                                       
    for row in footballTable:                                                   
        print row
```

This will show you something along the lines of:

```
{'Draws': '3', 'Wins': '26', 'Losses': '9', 'Goals Allowed': '36', 'Points': '87', 'Games': '38', 'Goals': '79', 'Team': 'Arsenal'}
{'Draws': '6', 'Wins': '24', 'Losses': '8', 'Goals Allowed': '30', 'Points': '80', 'Games': '38', 'Goals': '67', 'Team': 'Liverpool'}
{'Draws': '9', 'Wins': '24', 'Losses': '5', 'Goals Allowed': '45', 'Points': '77', 'Games': '38', 'Goals': '87', 'Team': 'Manchester United'}
...
```

You'll note that:

- The header row is handled for you automatically
- You can now refer to columns by name, rather than needing to rely on magic indexes (`i[5]`) in your code.  That is, you can ask for `i['Goals']` or `i['Goals Allowed']`.

With just a couple of additional lines in that loop you can probably have a solution to your problem.